# gradle minifyEnabled false in buildTypes debug issue

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, proguard

This question might seem like a "duplicate question" but I've been looking at the same issue in S.O. and Google and I haven't found anything so before downvoting please read the question closely.

Inside my buildTypes (build.gradle) I want to enable proguard only for release mode, so I set inside **debug** block `minifyEnabled false` but if I put a breakpoint in debug mode it's skipped, otherwise if I set `minifyEnabled false` also inside **release** block all works fine.
Just tried clean, rebuild, invalidate cache. Nothing seem to works.

This is my buildTypes block:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}
```

Has someone encountered the same problem?
Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Flag minifyEnabled stays for ProGuard, and it's turned off by default. So, in default setup both debug and release builds aren't using ProGuard, and parameter proguardFiles is effectively ignored